# How do I hide Emacs' "obsolete variable" warnings?

Tags: emacs

I've upgraded to Emacs 23.3 and now the `*Compile-Log*` buffer opens *constantly* with errors like:

```
Warning: `font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function' is an obsolete variable (as
    of Emacs 23.3); use `syntax-begin-function' instead.
```

I'm assuming the upstream authors will take care of these warnings in the future. Until then, how can I prevent these errors from appearing and opening a new window?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm currently back on 23.2 due to another issue, but I hacked a workaround for this issue while I was trying 23.3. It simply prevents the variable from being considered obsolete, but until Mumamo sorts itself out, that seemed preferable!

```
;; Mumamo is making emacs 23.3 freak out:
(when (and (equal emacs-major-version 23)
           (equal emacs-minor-version 3))
  (eval-after-load "bytecomp"
    '(add-to-list 'byte-compile-not-obsolete-vars
                  'font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function))
  ;; tramp-compat.el clobbers this variable!
  (eval-after-load "tramp-compat"
    '(add-to-list 'byte-compile-not-obsolete-vars
                  'font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function)))
```

Answer (score 7):

There are four levels of options for the warnings :

- warning-minimum-level
- warning-minimum-log-level
- warning-suppress-types
- warning-suppress-log-types

There are more information on the [Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Warning-Options.html).

Comment: So, to add to the above, you can add the following to custom-set-variables in your .emacs:  '(warning-minimum-level :error)

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by running this on the elisp:

```
sed -i.bak 's/font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function/syntax-begin-function/g' `find . -name '*.el' -exec grep -l 'font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function' {} \;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Phils's solution didn't work for me for some reason. Here's a more low-level way to do it.

```
(remprop 'flet 'byte-obsolete-info)
(remprop 'labels 'byte-obsolete-info)
```

Comment: this works for me but now I get `function ‘remprop’ from cl package called at`